# A macro definition in ADB source code

Tags: android, c, linux, adb

I'm reading the ADB source code of Android 4.0. The file I'm reading right now is system/core/adb/sysdeps.h. There is one thing that I cannot understand:

```
static __inline__  int  adb_write(int  fd, const void*  buf, size_t  len)
{
    return write(fd, buf, len);
}
#undef   write
#define  write  ___xxx_write
```

What does the last line mean? What is "___xxx_write"?

Answer (score 0):

They are wrapping the POSIX `write()` API call and then redefining `write` to an undefined symbol so it can not be used in the program. They want to ensure developers use `adb_write()` instead.

The `#undef write` makes sure the subsequent `#define write` does not get a "redefined" warning if the C library used already has a `write` macro defined.

6 years ago, `adb_write()` was nothing more than `write()` on Unix. In the latest, the error code is wrapped for special handling, which demonstrates the value of this technique.

```c
static __inline__ int adb_write(borrowed_fd fd, const void* buf, size_t len) {
    return TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(write(fd.get(), buf, len));
}
#undef   write
#define  write  ___xxx_write
```

From https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/e7f014da9c49c56367ae2dc3ba53c5dda3814c45/adb/sysdeps.h#499